# Memory Issue when loading images in UITableviewcell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimage

I'm loading images from the server in UItableViewCell.

Since Each Image takes 10MB size It cause memory problem.
App crashes Whenever I do scroll over the `tableView`

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    locationcellObject=[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSDictionary *temp= [sortedArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    locationcellObject.title.text=[temp objectForKey:@"locationtitle"];
    locationcellObject.subtitle_Lbl.text=[temp objectForKey:@"category"];
    NSString *trimmedtitle = [[temp objectForKey:@"locationtitle"]stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    NSString *name=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"images/%@.png",trimmedtitle];
    NSString *imageName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://my_URL_HERE/%@",name];
    _tempData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageName]];
    UIImage *display=[[UIImage alloc]initWithData:_tempData];
    locationcellObject.locationPic_img_View.image=display;
    locationcellObject.locationPic_img_View.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

    return locationcellObject;
}
```

Is there any Easy way to do it??

Comment: Where do you alloc your cell ?

Comment: why you are using 10MB images for cells ? an image of less size will be sufficient as it is probably will be scaled anyway (unless your cell size is as big as the image)

Comment: I have created an `NSObject` for the `Cell` and I've allocated it in `ViewDidLoad`

Comment: @giorashc yes My cells will take half of the screen

Answer (score 0):

1 ) you should do the downloading in the background 
2 ) make a thumbnail of the image (image with smaller size)

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0),^ {
_tempData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageName]];
UIImage *display=[[UIImage alloc]initWithData:_tempData];

//make a thumbnail of the image 

UIImage *display; 
CGSize destinationSize = ...;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(destinationSize);
[originalImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,destinationSize.width,destinationSize.height)];
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
//
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
//put result to main thread
locationcellObject.locationPic_img_View.image= newImage;
     });
});
```

Comment: `main_queue` image isn't displayed in the `UIImageViewCell`

Answer (score 0):

Download your images in background thread, download images with in the block. by this way two thread will be running in your app main thread and background thread. it will be reduces load on main thread.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    //Call your function or whatever work that needs to be done
    //Code in this part is run on a background thread

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {

        //Stop your activity indicator or anything else with the GUI
        //Code here is run on the main thread

    });
});
```

And also add downloaded images in cache using NSCache,by which next time your images will be loaded from cache,

you can check this [link](http://www.google.com/url?q=http://jaminya.com/index.php/en/component/content/article/39-ios/55-async-img-load&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNGJ8mmZKqdiGsAU5l2pwritsNGkLg) here you can find how to add images in cache

Answer (score 0):

Please refer [THIS](http://iosmadesimple.blogspot.in/2013/04/lazy-image-loading.html) tutorial. It describes fetching/loading  images in UItableView in efficient way.